# System References Error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, assemblies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZ2N.png)

I tried to add all missing assemblies but it is not working at all.

Comment: @ruchi-tang  Please provide a specific error description.What help you need exactly?
probably you should have a look here first : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no error but when i try to install missing packages, it gets install but Still no use..

Comment: The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\\AQS\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Workspace\AQS\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll' or one of its dependencies. System cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask

Comment: Likewise I am getting 45 errors.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems NuGet packages were committed to the repository and breaking everything. Deleting the project\project\packages directory from the repo should solve all build problems since NuGet fetches the packages automatically on build.

So, just try following below steps to fix the issue:

1. Locate your project’s **packages** folder
2. Delete the package folder
3. Check in
4. Rebuild your project

Reference this thread : [Resolved: The “Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc” task could not be loaded from the assembly.](https://kx.cloudingenium.com/programming/net/resolved-microsoft-codeanalysis-buildtasks-csc-task-not-loaded-assembly/)

**UPDATE:**

The yellow exclamation marks issue should be related to the reference path. The system cannot find the references, seems the original reference path changed.

Just try to reinstall the package, you can use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```